# python index() not working

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to print the filename '`xyz.0.html`' in the console. It is spitting out an error `"substring not found"`

files in directory:

```
xyz.0.html
xyz.1.html
xyz.2.html
```

python

```
for name in glob.glob('*html'):
  if name.index('.0.html'):
    print name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want

```
if '.0.html' in name:
```

Or,

```
if name.endswith('.0.html'):
```

Your version raises an error if the substring isn't in the string (and it will evaluate to `False` if the substring is at the start of the string) since the `index` method returns the index in the string where the substring was found (or raises an exception if the substring wasn't found).

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?

```
>>> "xyz.0.html".endswith(".0.html")
True
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if ".0.html" in name: 
   print name
```

or

```
if name.endswith(".0.html"):
      print name
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is just what it says.  When you call `name.index('0.html')` on the name `"xyz.1.html"`, the string is not found.  `index` raises an error in this case.  If you don't want this, you can use the `find` method instead (which returns -1 if the substring is not found), or you can catch the exception.

Comment: +1 - this is a good why, the other answers only tell you other (better) ways of doing it, not why the version in the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python's generator

```
print [name for name in glob.glob('*html') if name.endswith(".0.html")]
```

Comment: Just to nit-pick, that's a list comprehension, not a generator.  Also, that prints the names as a list compared to a vertical column of names which may or may not matter.

Comment: @mgilson thanks, but It acts like generator, and it creates a list, what is the problem of this code?